# What message will UIViewController will receive when a the iPhone receive a telephone call?

Tags: iphone, uikit

What message will UIViewController will receive when a the iPhone receive a telephone call?

Answer (score 0):

It will Call UIviewController's

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

delegate method...

Comment: Actually that's in UIApplicationDelegate